# How to remove 10 % of the lines of a (large) file?

Tags: bash, sed, split

I have some files (some > 30) that I want to remove the first 10% of their lines (starting at beginning).

With the help of other Stack Overflow users, I've tried to do something like this:

```
declare -a t
declare -a z
for j in {0..31}; do
    t[$j]=$(wc -l  < h_$j)
    z[$j]=$(echo "${t[$i]}"/10 | bc)
    sed "1,${z[$j]}d" h_$j > hh_$j
done
```

But for some files, and I have no idea why, it doesn't work. I though about `split`, but I couldn't find any option that allow me to only remove the first 10 % without generating 10 different files with 10 % of the original file.

Comment: `split` seems like a reasonable approach: for each file, calculate 10%, `split` at that boundary, remove the first file (eg `rm xaa`), cat the rest back together.

Comment: $i should be $j, I guess. There's no assignment to i in your example.

Comment: Note that you really don't need to use arrays unless you need to know after the loop how big the files were before you started.  You could simply use `t=…` and `z=…` and `sed "1,${z}d" …` (where the `{}` are needed because `$zd` substitutes a different variable).  Some versions of `sed` have a `-i` option to overwrite the original; use with caution! (Note that `-i .bak` creates a backup and works on both Linux and Mac OS X; the extension is optional with GNU `sed`).

Comment: As to why it doesn't work on some files, the simplest explanation might be "the files don't contain lines" (for example, they're executables), or "they contain binary data" (ASCII NUL characters mess things up royally), or "the lines they contain are just too long" (JSON — I'm looking at you!).

Answer (score 3):

#### Using `tail`

This uses `tail` to remove the first 10% of lines from `file`:

```
tail -n+$(( $(wc -l <file) / 10 )) file
```

#### Using `sed`

```
sed -n "$(( $(wc -l <file) / 10 ))",'$ p' file
```

If you want to change the file in place, use sed's `-i` option:

```
sed -i -n "$(( $(wc -l <file) / 10 ))",'$ p' file
```

For non-GNU `sed` (OSX, etc), the option `-i` may require an argument specifying the extension of a back-up file.